# Draw a rectangle and retain the background info

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, drawing

In c# I have a panel with **thousands** of coordinates plotted and need to draw a rectangle to zoom into.

Drawing the rectangle is not a problem.

The problem is drawing the rectangle on top of the data without having to replot the data all the time.

I am using the `onPaint` event. I hope someone can understand and help

Comment: Are you using any library? Tool?

Comment: Share your source,please

Comment: Don't fill the rectangle?

Comment: if I remember correctly there is a way of painting only a portion of the painting area, I can't recall the specifics now though. Would repainting only the portion covered by the rectangle work for you?

Comment: I am not using any library tool, just normal mouse up down and move. Also I have a filled in blue area that I plot onto, and removing the fill makes no difference. Someone suggested that I save a copy of the background as an image,  load the image and draw the rectangle on top of the image. If so how would I go about that

Comment: Yes, thousands of data should be collected into a Bitmap! - you can combine a BackgroundImage with plotting the latest Points and the selection rectangle or even a DrawImage..

Comment: See [here for a discussion with an example!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27623365/existing-graphics-into-bitmap/27647011?s=1|8.1372#27647011)

Comment: @TaW thank you for your example. I have been away for the last few days and back now. Will try it and see if that sorts out the problem. Appreciate the effort